# Stylus - Hash causing error

Tags: css, hash, stylus

I'm trying to use a hash in Stylus to group all the properties of my buttons. Here is the hash:

global_constants.styl:

```
brand-colour = #FC4747
button-hover-colour = #ff8282
button-style = 
    {   font: 200 16px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif,
        border: 1px solid brand-colour,
        border-radius: 6px,
        '&:hover': {
            background-color: #ff8282
        }
    }
```

And the client (override_multiselect.styl):

```
@require "global_constants"

button.multiselect 
    {button-style}

ul.multiselect-container 
    width 100%

span.multiselect-selected-text
    color brand-colour
    text-transform uppercase
    font button-style[font]
```

I'm getting this error:

> > ParseError: stylus/global_constants.styl:7:6    3| button-style =     4|     {   the-font: 200 16px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial,
> >     sans-serif,    5|         the-border: 1px solid brand-colour,    6|
> >     the-border-radius: 6px    7|     }
> >     -----------^
>
> invalid right-hand side operand in assignment, got "outdent"

How do I get rid of the error and apply all of the `button-style` styles to `button.multiselect` and apply the `button-style[font]` to `span.multiselect-selected-text`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you get the error because `,` is a separator for key-value pairs of the hash. You can use your approach (with string + `unquote` to get the real value), or you can escape the commas with `\`:

```
font: 200 16px 'Helvetica Neue'\, Helvetica\, Arial\, sans-serif,
```

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing this too thanks. The first parenthesis also needs to be on the same line as the '=' for it to compile

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the indentation to contain the opening parenthesis on the same line as the "=", and also escape my commas in the font, like this:

```
brand-colour = #FC4747
button-hover-colour = #ff8282
button-style = {   font: 200 16px 'Helvetica Neue'\, Helvetica\, Arial\, sans-serif,
        border: 1px solid brand-colour,
        border-radius: 6px,
        height: 64px,
        '&:hover': {
            background-color: #ff8282
        }
    }
```